# Set variable inside cursor for to use in select statement

Tags: mysql, cursors

This is my query to create procedure, but its displaying error like :

> 'DECLARE curBalRows CURSOR FOR
>
> select if(

What I'm missing here?

```
    DELIMITER $$

drop procedure if exists `getAllBalanceRowsUpdate`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllBalanceRowsUpdate`(
    IN `p_ind` INT(20), 
    IN `p_scode` VARCHAR(200)
) 


BEGIN

DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE balanced DECIMAL(20,3) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE orderId INT DEFAULT 0;

select @redeem_unit = (SELECT sum(allotted_unit) from orders where investor_id=p_ind and scheme_code=p_scode and type='R' and status in ('approved', 'awaiting'));
select @balance=0;
select @redeem_unit = round( ifnull( @redeem_unit, @redeem_unit:=0), 3 );

DECLARE curBalRows CURSOR FOR 



select if( allotted_unit >= @redeem_unit, @balance:= allotted_unit - @redeem_unit, @balance:= 0 ) as balanced, if( allotted_unit >= @redeem_unit, @redeem_unit:=0, @redeem_unit:= @redeem_unit-allotted_unit ) as leftunit, order_id, allotted_unit, allotted_nav, allotted_nav*@balance as balanceAmount, datetime from orders where investor_id = p_ind and orders.scheme_code =p_scode and type in ('L', 'S') and status = 'APPROVED';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

OPEN curBalRows;

getRows: LOOP
    FETCH curBalRows INTO balanced, orderId;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getRows;
        END IF;

                UPDATE orders SET balance=balanced where order_id=orderId;

END LOOP getRows;
CLOSE curBalRows;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE statement must posess at the beginning of BEGIN-END block, before any other statements. Use nested BEGIN-END:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

drop procedure if exists `getAllBalanceRowsUpdate`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllBalanceRowsUpdate`(
IN `p_ind` INT(20), 
IN `p_scode` VARCHAR(200)
) 

BEGIN

    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE balanced DECIMAL(20,3) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE orderId INT DEFAULT 0;

    select @redeem_unit = (SELECT sum(allotted_unit) from orders where investor_id=p_ind and scheme_code=p_scode and type='R' and status in ('approved', 'awaiting'));
    select @balance=0;
    select @redeem_unit = round( ifnull( @redeem_unit, @redeem_unit:=0), 3 );

    BEGIN  -- add nested BEGIN-END block

        DECLARE curBalRows CURSOR FOR 
        select if( allotted_unit >= @redeem_unit, @balance:= allotted_unit - @redeem_unit, @balance:= 0 ) as balanced, if( allotted_unit >= @redeem_unit, @redeem_unit:=0, @redeem_unit:= @redeem_unit-allotted_unit ) as leftunit, order_id, allotted_unit, allotted_nav, allotted_nav*@balance as balanceAmount, datetime from orders where investor_id = p_ind and orders.scheme_code =p_scode and type in ('L', 'S') and status = 'APPROVED';

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

        OPEN curBalRows;

        getRows: LOOP
            FETCH curBalRows INTO balanced, orderId;
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getRows;
            END IF;

            UPDATE orders SET balance=balanced where order_id=orderId;

        END LOOP getRows;
        CLOSE curBalRows;

    END;  -- finalize nested BEGIN-END block

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

PS. Remember - declared construction exists only within the block where it is defined. So whole code between cursor declaration and cursor closing must be included into the block - finalizing `END` cannot be placed earlier.

Comment: In this case @redeem_unit can't be modified and accessible in BEGIN Block of cursor

Comment: @ManoharKumar ??? But if you see this then declare additional variable in inner block between declaring handler and opening cursor, copy the value into it, and use it instead original variable.